# D-Bus related runtime crash when trying to open SDL2 window

Tags: c++, linux, sdl, sdl-2, dbus

On my system, when running the following snippet of C++ code compiled with either clang or gcc

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    printf("Hi");
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindow("", 0, 0, 800, 600, 0);
    printf("Bye");
}
```

then I get the following output at runtime

```
process 9360: arguments to dbus_connection_open_private() were incorrect, assertion "address != NULL" failed in file dbus-connection.c line 2664.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Hi
```

I have had this same problem when attempting to compile and run SDL2 code which has worked on another machine, although running the binary works if it is compiled on that machine.

I am running Antergos Linux and should be on the latest versions of SDL2 and D-Bus (I run updates regularly through pacman). I would appreciate any help and would be happy to answer any further questions, thank you.

Comment: Quick search through SDL source code suggests it never calls said function without first checking `addr` for NULL. Get SDL from hg, build it and link with it. If problem persists (which is unlikely), build SDL with debugging symbols and run in debugger to see stacktrace and actual values.

Comment: I've seen something like that recently on Ubuntu. It wasn't affecting the correct functionning of the application.

Comment: @Velkan I suppose it is controlled by `DBUS_FATAL_WARNINGS` envvar. Default value seems to be 1, so it should `abort()` on this error, ending calling program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my install of SDL2. I compiled and installed from source, and now SDL2 works just fine.